# Can I use the contains method on every object?

Tags: java, methods, contains

Can the `contains` method be used on instances of classes I've written myself?

I've created a class named `Ana` and in another class, I've created two instance of it called `cookie` and `maccaroni`. This is one of them:

```
Ana cookie = new Ana(cc.c, 20, 450);
```

At some point I am trying to invoke

```
if (maccaroni.contains(cookie.image(), cookie.xi(), cookie.yi())
{
    return true;
}
```

but Netbeans underlined it to indicate a mistake. When I hovered over it, it said:

> ```
> no suitable method found for contains(Image,int,int)
>     method Component.contains(int,int) is not applicable
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>     method Component.contains(Point) is not applicable
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>     method JComponent.contains(int,int) is not applicable
>       (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
> ```

Why the following code is regarded as a mistake by Netbeans?

This is the class I'm referring to.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Ana extends JComponent
{
    public static Image p;
    public static int xx;
    public static int yy;

    public Ana(Image io, int x, int y)
    {
        p = io;
        xx = x;
        yy = y;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
       g.drawImage(p, xx, yy, null);
    }


    public Image image()
    {
        return p;
    }

    public int xi()
    {
        return xx;
    }

    public int yi()
    {
        return yy;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*What kind of error is in this code*" why do you think that there is error? Did you get any error message? Could you include it in your question?

Comment: @Parta What type of thing is `maccaroni`?

Comment: `JComponent.contains(int x, int y)` takes two integer arguments. But I don't know if `maccaroni` is a `JComponent`.

Comment: BTW are you sure that your fields should be `static`? Do you know what `static` means? Also most probably they should be `private`.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I forgot to mention it. It's an instance of Ana class just like cookie.

Comment: You really should do what @Pshemo suggested and include any error message in the question.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  I can't understand what you're trying to do in the posted code.

Comment: The short answer to your question is that no Ana objects can use the `contains(Image, int, int)` method, because that method doesn't exist in Ana or its subclasses.  All Ana objects can use the `contains(int, int)` method because it exists in JComponent.  However, I doubt that answer is really what you are looking for, so if you can provide more details, that would help.

Comment: @Erik G.Hagstrom I didn't compile the file, yet. The netbean simply underlined it to indicate an error. Ana class has JComponent as a superclass, I simply took of the Image object and now it works., with only two integers. I wanted to say my thanks as soon as I corrected it, only to see that you have put on hold my question. I've been very clear.  I'm no expert in Java and it's natural for me to make mistakes. Putting on hold my question was an extremely mean move from your side and the rest of them.

Comment: Mistakes are to be expected and we're here to help. But the questions and answers on this site are supposed to be useful to others as well. If you don't follow the directions that you saw when you signed up, and if you ignore the instructions that more experienced users give you, you end up writing a bad question. And we will close bad questions. I'm sorry you felt slighted, but there was no enmity directed at you personally. And if you want to put in a little more effort and improve the question it can be reopened.

Comment: @Ironache That was exactly the question I was looking for. Erick G. Hagstrom answered it first. I think the question was very clear. I simply asked whenever I could use the contains method on every type of the objects. The object I was asking for was not an inherited one ,so I had to add the class I've written.

Comment: @Erik G. Hagstrom The question was quite quite useful for the others as well. I'm sure of it.

Comment: @PartaCana Purpose of Stack Overflow is to be searchable repository of programming questions and answers. So it is very important for question to maximize its searchability (like introducing exact error message which others could face, or by asking specific question which others also could use in their searching queries). Questions also need to be clear and this is main problem with it now. We don't know what exact problem you are facing. We don't even know which `contains` method you want to invoke (how should it work?, where it is defined?).

Comment: About "I didn't compile the file, yet. The netbean simply underlined it to indicate an error." NetBeans (and most of other IDEs) probably compile your code each time you change it (and save it), and underlined text usually contain description/tooltip about what is wrong with it like shown on this picture http://www.stpe.se/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/netbeans-invalid-js-warning.png. If you don't see such description then maybe try to compile it manually in console using `javac` and include errors you got in your question.

Comment: Anyway don't take what we say personally. We are not judging person, but question. If we see that something in post (regardless if it is question or answer) could or should be improved then we usually inform OP about it to make Stack Overflow as useful for future readers as possible.

Comment: @Pshemo I don't know ,where the 'contains' method is defined. I've found some code online and I simply am changing it to fit my goal. That code was about some draggable rectangle and I am changing it to a draggable image.

Comment: @PartaCana Thanks for editing. I and two others so far have voted to reopen this question.

Comment: @Pshemo My question was very clear. I don't know where it is defined, but I am sure you knew what I was talking about, since two of you posted the same answer and I solved the problem. How would they know the answer,if the question was that unclear?

Comment: By "*My question was very clear.*" I am assuming you are referring to "*Can the contains method be used on instances of classes I've written myself?*". This can be answered by compiler. If it is not giving you error then you can. If it gives error then you can't, at least in a way you are doing it now. But it is hard to give better answer since solution would depend on what exact error you got and what you really want to achieve here (which we still not clear, we don't see your implementation of such method, and none of superclass defines it, so all we can do here is guess).

Comment: @Pshemo Okay, I'll add the message that netbeans says to me when I hover on the mistake. Any other detail I forgot to mention?

Comment: Your question looks a lot better now. I edited it a little to add some formatting and clear repeated info. Hope you don't mind. I also edited posted answer to clarify it. IMO it answers your question (at least in its current form). I voted to reopen your question.

Comment: Anyway if you would like to get help in creation of such method (since it doesn't exist yet and we don't know what it should do) consider explaining it more. But don't do it in this question since adding new requirements could invalidate already posted answer. If you decide to ask for assistance post new follow-up question and explain what you want to achieve. Also to avoid down-votes include your attempts (more info at ["what have you tried?"](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)).

Comment: @Pshemo I have already corrected the problem. I am using the contains method of JComponent class.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `contains()` method defined in `Ana`. There is a `contains()` method defined in `JComponent`. It takes two integers. You're trying to invoke it with an image and two integers. You can probably get what you need by writing it like this:

```
if (maccaroni.contains(cookie.xi(), cookie.yi())
{
    return true;
}
```

So the kind of error in this code is: it's a compile error. NetBeans isn't just underlining it, there is a message somewhere on your screen telling you what is wrong. You may have to mouse over the underline or look in a different section of the screen--I don't use NetBeans on a regular basis so I don't recall exactly--but I assure you the message is there.

And no, you can't invoke `contains()` on *any* object, only on objects which classes define a `contains()` method (with proper parameters), or that inherit such a method from one of their supertypes (from an ancestor class or interface they implement).

Methods which all objects could use are those inherited from `java.lang.Object` class, since all classes explicitly or implicitly extend it (parent of parent of parent... finally will need to extend the `Object` class).

But there is no `contains(Image, int, int)` method defined on `java.lang.Object`. The only `contains()` method available to instances of the `Ana` class is the one inherited from `JComponent` which is `contains(int, int)`. As you see it accepts two `int` arguments, which prevents you from using it with the additional `Image` argument.

By the way, as @PShemo has noted, your fields `p`, `xx` and `yy` should likely be `private` and most definitely *not* `static`.

Comment: I edited your answer (I tried to clarify it a little). If you don't like my chances feel free to rollback my edit.